# What do you call the sharp end of a slide (slide as in playground)?

Tags: word-request

In other words, what do you call this?

[image]

Few options pop in my mind: the end of the slide, the foot of the slide, but I'm not a native speaker so I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of us would just say "the bottom" of the slide. Especially if we were children, who are the ones who use it; children generally find simple ways to say things.

One might also refer to the "foot" of the slide. I don't think I would use "end" because it isn't clear whether I'm talking about the top end or the bottom end.

I also found [this](https://www.playsetparts.com/multi-piece-scoop-slide/) advertisement for a "multi-piece scoop slide," which has an "entrance" (top) section, an "exit" (bottom) section, and a variable number of "insert" (middle) sections, in order to accommodate different deck heights. So, perhaps people in the business of manufacturing slides would call the bottom the "exit."